# Reflection and Private Native Methods

Tags: java, reflection

I am using reflection to dynamically call some methods from extended class. Unfortunately one of these methods is declared as private native and as soon as I make the call... I receive the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.something.somewhere.MyThing ca
n not access a member of class com.something.somewhere.AnotherThing with modifier
s "private native"
```

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you calling `setAccessible(true)` on the Method before invoking it?

Comment: +1 - this is the workaround.  But the OP should ask him/herself if it is a good idea to be calling the **private** methods of another class ...

Comment: @Pass - my guess is that it didn't work because the method is simply not designed to be used in the way you are using it.  The fact that it is declared as `private` is a big hint that you shouldn't be *trying to* call it.

Comment: thanks for the clarification... I ended up modifying the bytecode which did the trick... the reason I had to do this was because of a ugly monkey patch. thanks again.